# php how to serve file but NOT for download

Tags: php

The code below forces browser to fire a prompt to save/open file (https://kb.wisc.edu/images/group27/13334/open-prompt.PNG) even if it's a image or pdf file.

I want images to be opened as usual, pdf files to be displayed in browser. And of course other files that are not supported by browser like zip, rar, doc, xls etc will fire a save file dialog.

Edit:
My intention is not to block client to save the file of course they can save it that's impossible. I want to serve let say images as PHP files like main.php?file=randomcode (which is stored in database) but not as /images/somefilename.jpg . My code forces client to download it but I want to display it.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "." . $fileinfo["file_extension"] . "\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
if ($fp) {
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $cur_data = fread($fp, 1024);
        echo $cur_data;
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: Could not the read file.";
}
```

Comment: every single thing you ever put on the internet is downloaded if it ever reaches a web browser. what is your **actual** question?

Comment: this code forces browser to fire a prompt to save/open file (https://kb.wisc.edu/images/group27/13334/open-prompt.PNG) even it's a image or pdf (of course this requires adobe reader plugin). I want images to be opened as usual, pdf files to be displayed in browser. And of course other files that are not supported by browser like zip, rar, doc, xls etc will fire a save file dialog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if the content type is set to octate stream then it will defenetly transfer the file means user will force download it. you have to set content type accordingly to open it in browser

for example if type is image then

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
```

etc.

and if its image or pdf then remove Content-Disposition: header

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently you know the file extension so you could do:

```
if(in_array($fileinfo["file_extension"], array('jpg', 'png', 'gif')) {

    // set header for viewing the image

    $mime_type = $fileinfo["file_extension"];
    if($mime_type == 'jpg') {
        $mime_type = 'jpeg';
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/' . $mime_type);

}
else {
    // set headers for downloading the file
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me example headers for let say jpg

Comment: The MIME type for JPEG files is image/jpeg, NOT image/jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it's up to the client what to do with the content it receives.  One thing you can do is get rid of the `Content-disposition` header:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "." . $fileinfo["file_extension"] . "\";");
```

(Or at least get rid of it conditionally, depending on specific factors about the file.)  What this header does is tell the client that the content being returned is a "file" (you even provide a suggested name for the file) and should be treated as such.  HTTP has no native concept of "files" so this header exists specifically to identify something as a "file."

By not supplying that header, you're not suggesting to the client that the content is a file.  The client may still *infer* that it's a file and treat it as such (which you can't control), but from your end all you'd be doing is returning the content itself.